# TypeScript: Get Non-Inherited Properties of Class

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

```
class A {
    baseField: number;
}

class B extends A {
    nonInherited: number;
}

type onlyNonInherited = PickNonInherited<B>;
```

I need my `onlyNonInherited` type to be equal to the following:

```
interface NonInherited {
    nonInherited: number;
}
```

What should be the definition of `PickNonInherited`?
I've tried to read many posts, but found no solution :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do this by only looking at the type `B`. You can however do something like

```
type OnlyNonInherited = Omit<B, keyof A>;
```